# GLSL Shader Producing Unwanted Results

Tags: opengl, glsl

I cannot get the following shader to work.

Vertex Shader

```
#version 430

in vec4 vPosition;
in vec4 vColor;
in vec2 vTexCoord;
in vec3 vNormal;
in vec3 vTangent;
in vec3 vBitangent;

//out vec4 color;
out vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 Model;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Projection;

out vec3 LightDirection_cameraspace;
out vec3 Position_worldspace;
uniform vec3 LightPosition;
out vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace;

out vec3 LightDirection_tangentspace;
out vec3 EyeDirection_tangentspace;

void main()
{
        gl_Position = Projection * View * Model * vPosition;

        Position_worldspace = (Model * vPosition).xyz;

        vec3 vertexPosition_cameraspace = (View * Model * vPosition).xyz;
        EyeDirection_cameraspace = vec3(0, 0, 0) - vertexPosition_cameraspace;

        vec3 LightPosition_cameraspace = (View * vec4(LightPosition, 1)).xyz;
        LightDirection_cameraspace = LightPosition_cameraspace + EyeDirection_cameraspace;

        texCoord = vTexCoord;

        mat4 ModelView = View * Model;
        mat3 MV3x3 = mat3(ModelView);
        vec3 vertexTangent_cameraspace = MV3x3 * vTangent;
        vec3 vertexBitangent_cameraspace = MV3x3 * vBitangent;
        vec3 vertexNormal_cameraspace = MV3x3 * vNormal;

        mat3 TBN = transpose(mat3(
                vertexTangent_cameraspace,
                vertexBitangent_cameraspace,
                vertexNormal_cameraspace
        ));

        LightDirection_tangentspace = TBN * LightDirection_cameraspace;
        EyeDirection_tangentspace = TBN * EyeDirection_cameraspace;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 430

in vec4 vColor;
in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 fColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec3 Position_worldspace;
in vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace;
uniform vec3 LightPosition;

//uniform sampler2D DiffuseTex; pretty much just tex
uniform sampler2D NormalTex;
uniform sampler2D SpecularTex;

in vec3 LightDirection_tangentspace;
in vec3 EyeDirection_tangentspace;

void main()
{
        vec3 LightColor = vec3(1, 1, 1);
        float LightPower = 50.0f;

        //vec3 MaterialDiffuseColor = texture2D(tex, texCoord).rgb; // EDITABLE VALU 3 LINE
        //vec3 MaterialAmbientColor = vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1) * MaterialDiffuseColor;
        //vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = texture2D(SpecularTex, texCoord).rgb * 0.3;
        vec3 MaterialDiffuseColor = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        vec3 MaterialAmbientColor = vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
        vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = vec3(1, 1, 1);

        vec3 TextureNormal_tangentspace = normalize(texture2D(NormalTex, vec2(texCoord.x, texCoord.y)).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0); // EDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDIT this line if upside down

        float distance = length(LightPosition - Position_worldspace);

        vec3 n = TextureNormal_tangentspace;
        vec3 l = normalize(LightDirection_tangentspace);

        float cosTheta = clamp(dot(n, l), 0, 1);

        vec3 E = normalize(EyeDirection_tangentspace);
        vec3 R = reflect(-l, n);

        float cosAlpha = clamp(dot(E, R), 0, 1);

        fColor = vec4(MaterialAmbientColor + MaterialDiffuseColor * LightColor * LightPower * cosTheta / (distance*distance) + MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * LightPower * pow(cosAlpha,5) / (distance*distance), 1.0);


}
```

Here's an imgur album with photos including the diffuse, specular, and normal maps as well as the image the program produces. https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8vck.jpg

P.S. The shader DOES compile, it just does not produce the desired image.

Comment: You should post your code directly here. If you need help posting your code here, say so.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Added the code to the post and made a seperate imgur album for the pictures.

Comment: Did you reverse fragment and vertex shaders? They seem backwards to me. Also, what happens if you change your fragment shader to output a solid color, and work up from there? For example, just output the `MaterialAmbientColor`. Then if that works add in `MaterialDiffuseColor` unmodified by light color, etc. And build it up as you go.

Comment: Yeah, sorry they were mixed up. I'll try what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: So far, it seems that my cosTheta is causing the issue, but im not sure why. I'm thinking its either my tangent/bitangents or the calculations im doing with them.

Comment: My calculations seem to be all correct, I think there is something wrong with the tangents and bitangents i've generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, nice code! I've seen shaders far more difficult to read than that.

You can simplify the projection/view/model transformations so there are no duplicates...

```
vec4 worldPosition = Modle * vPosition;
vec4 cameraPosition = View * worldPosition;
vec4 clipPosition = Projection * cameraPosition;
gl_Position = clipPosition;
```

To transform the normal, you need a normal matrix (inverse transpose modelview), otherwise scales can mess things up.

It's pretty common to compute `LightPosition_cameraspace` outside the shader, since it doesn't change. You also don't need `Position_worldspace` as `distance` can be computed in camera/eye space. `View * Model` is pretty expensive, and can be computed once and passed in. Now that `View` isn't needed, you can simply replace both `View` and `Model` with the single `ModelView` matrix.

The binormal can be computed implicitly from the normal and tangent via a cross product. This saves a fair bit of storage and memory bandwidth. If your normal/tangent are not perpendicular it may be necessary to use two cross products to ensure all three are orthonormal.

The main problem seems to be in your last line...

```
fColor = vec4(
    MaterialAmbientColor
    + (
        MaterialDiffuseColor * LightColor * LightPower * cosTheta
        / (distance*distance)
      )
    + (
        MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * LightPower * pow(cosAlpha,5)
        / (distance*distance)
      )
    , 1.0);
```

`LightPower` is scaling your diffuse and specular components. Change to the following

```
float attenuation = 1.0/distance*distance; //just for readability

fColor = vec4(
    MaterialAmbientColor
    + (
        MaterialDiffuseColor * LightColor * cosTheta * attenuation
      )
    + (
        MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * pow(cosAlpha, LightPower) * attenuation
      )
    , 1.0);
```

If after this you're still not seeing the right result, you'll have to start doing some debugging of each variable to narrow down the trouble maker. For example, as @user1118321 suggested check the colours aren't just black or something. Check your `LightDirection_tangentspace` with `fColor = vec4(l,1)` - you might look for (0,0,1)/blue for the parts that face the light directly. Make sure tangent/normals/light position are non-zero, the normal texture is bound etc (`fColor = vec4(n,1)`).

Comment: Thanks to this, i've gotten somewhere. However, I need to fix the funky lighting in the center there. http://i.imgur.com/y0qXepM.png

Comment: Turns out I was only calculating my tangents partly correctly, giving the funky lighting. Final result: http://i.imgur.com/b31aELQ.png